# PyCharm: Forcing Django Template Syntax Highligting

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've just installed PyCharm, and have opened an existing project with multiple apps. 
When I open django templates, they are highlighted as if plain HTML, i.e. `{% block %}` elements and `{{variable}}` references are not treated specially.

Is there any way I can force it to use the django template syntax highlighter for these files? Or am I doing something wrong?

The project is configured as a django project.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

File » Settings » Template language, do you have Template language setting set to django?

Comment: Brilliant, I knew it would be something simple. Thanks very much.

Comment: As of PyCharm 3.x, it's in File » Settings » Python Template Languages. I used this same setting to activate syntax highlight in .js files that I'm using as templates.

Comment: Using the green + icon, you can add filetypes too. This helped me with Django templates used for plain-text emails.

Comment: In OS X, PyCharm >> Preferences >> Languages & Frameworks >>  Python Template Languages

Comment: This feature does not exist in the community edition.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079540/pycharm-switch-python-template-language-to-django

Comment: Thank you so much. I created my Django project from the command line and then opened it in Pycharm. Never knew there was an additional setting. Had assumed it would see the entire project and set it accordingly.