# Pycharm switch Python Template Language to Django

Tags: pycharm

I've recently started up a django project on a new computer and recently found pycharm and am loving it so far. I've searched for my question online and read that setting pycharm to recognize django template syntax is as easy as settings -> Python Template Language -> Select Django from the dropdown.

Well that's all well and good, but this tab doesn't seem to exist for me.

[image: Where is it :(?]

The closest thing I can see is "Live Templates", but this does not seem to be the tab I'm looking for. Am I missing a plugin or something?

I'm sorry for this nub question, I just couldn't seem to find anyone having the same issue. Sorry if it's right in front of my eyes and I'm just being a dud.

Comment: have you checked languages and frameworks?

Comment: Yes, I've checked all the tabs. The only options under there are "Schemas and DTDs" and "Jupyter Notebook". Additionally, I've used the search bar to search for templates and it only brings up the "Live Templates" mentioned in the post.

Comment: I can't find "Python Template Languages" under "Languages & Frameworks" either. Only options under there are "Schemas and DTDs" and "Jupyter Notebook" for me as well. I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2018.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be using the Community Edition which is not full featured and probably does not include Web Development.

Comment: Thanks--none of the documentation I found indicates that it's only in the Professional edition, but that was the cause.  https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 4):

Should be here, under **Languages & Frameworks**

[image: screenshot of what you are looking]

[I got this image from following this tutorial](https://joshuahunter.com/posts/using-cookiecutter-to-jumpstart-a-django-project-on-windows-with-pycharm/) I do however not have Django either on my Pycharm and I am further reading for ways to add it.

When I went on and installed django with pipenv, at reopening pycharm it was prompted to me that Paid version has specific stuff for Django and was linked to the site where it said full-stack stuff was added so looks like as you say: **this is a pay thing**.